# Set a deadline time schedule to a DAG that waits for a TriggerDagRunOperator?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Due to some requirements, we need to implement a DAG that not-really depends on another one. The first DAG is due to finish with a `TriggerDagRunOperator` to call the second one. However, as the execution time needed for the first one is very variable, we want to set a "deadline" schedule. So, when the time reaches that "deadline", the second DAG starts directly, without waiting the first one.

Is there a way to implement this ? If so, how can I do it and how can I make the first DAG, if the second already started, to avoid the calling of the TriggerDagRunOperator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it by doing a workaround. I leave the solution here:

Instead of using a `TriggerDagRunOperator` at the end of the DAG 1, I put a `ExternalTaskSensor` at the beginning of the DAG 2 with a timeout and pokes the last task from DAG 1.

This way, if the DAG 1 finishes its last task before the timeout happens, the sensor will start with DAG2. In case of reaching the timeout, the sensor would fail, but the following task, with a trigger `'all_done'` will execute anyways.